# ajax, variable not defined?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I cant find whats is wrong with my code. When printing the json file from the post_receiver.php, the json is printed accordingly.

The JSON printed from the post_receiver.php

```
     <?php 
      session_start();
      ob_start();                    
      require_once('../../mysqlConnector/mysql_connect.php');
       $result_array = array();

   $query="SELECT COUNT(initID) AS count, urgency, crime, initID, TIMESTAMPDIFF( minute,dateanalyzed,NOW()) AS minuteDiff FROM initialanalysis WHERE commanderR='0' AND stationID='{$_SESSION['stationID']}';";

 $result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      array_push($result_array, $row);

      }

                            }
    echo json_encode($result_array);
                            ?>
```

Result from above:

```
[{"count":"10","urgency":"Low","crime":"Firearm","initID":"5","minuteDiff":"329"}]
```

my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "post_receiver.php",
        data: {
            'count': count,
            'urgency': urgency
        },...
```

the 'count' and 'urgency' variable is not defined, i am not that familiar with JSON format...

Comment: The `data` field specifies what request parameters are *sent* to the server. Do you want to send a `count` and `urquency` value, or do you want to extract them from the response?

Comment: @PeterMader i want to extract the value from the response

Answer (score 1):

In your `success` callback, you get a `data` string, which contains the response. To parse it as JSON, use the `json` `dataType` setting:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'post_receiver.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    // 'data' contains the parsed JSON
    console.log('Count:', data[0].count); // read the values from the JS object and log them to the console
    console.log('Urgency:', data[0].urgency);
  }
});
```

Comment: this would not work. instead of success ajax, it went to the error catcher.

Comment: added my php code, it just print the result in console. "error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, exception) {  console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);"

Comment: I don't need to see the `error` callback, I need the error message. What is printed to the error console?